# How do I get file path with Handlebars templates?

Tags: javascript, webpack, handlebars.js

I am using Webpack and Handlebars templates:

index.html

```
{{> head.html}}
```

head.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
<title>...</title>
```

Works like a charm. Now I've added a folder next to `index.html`:

```
/index.html
/docs/index.html
```

Both file import the same `head.html`. However, the one from the docs folder will have an error in the console because the stylehsheet is not loaded. I could have solved this by passing another variable to it, e.g.:

```
{{> head.html webRoot="."}}
```

and

```
{{> head.html webRoot=".."}}
```

and change `head.html` to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{webRoot}}/style.css" />
<title>...</title>
```

However, I hope to think Handlebars has some built-in variable for that. Is there any?

Comment: No, Handlebars is a templating engine, not a site builder. It's not aware of your site's file structure

Comment: @blex, I first saw this feature in https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include (see @@webRoot) and it was very useful. Too bad handlebars doesn't have this!

Comment: Well, Gulp and Handlebars are not really comparable, they are not doing the same thing. You can't expect a templating engine (whose goal is to render **a** template, not a site) to be aware of what you are going to do with that render (build a site with a certain structure). But nothing prevents you from providing that `webRoot` variable to your template when you render it. You mentioned using Webpack. How do you render each page?

Comment: I use this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-webpack-plugin. So ideally it has to know that I have an output folder and can check if the resulting file is in that folder or in any of its subfolders.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure you can do that with this plugin. Maybe you should create an issue [here](https://github.com/sagold/handlebars-webpack-plugin/issues) and ask them if it's possible to do with their plugin, or if they can implement it. You might get more luck